# Allow the contents of a server port to be accessible to public

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, tcp, port-forwarding

I have a live, automatically updating plot(using Bokeh) in python being displayed in a remote Linux server(set up by my university for me) at its port 127.0.0.1:5006. Usually, I have to connect to the server through SSH with a port forwarding enabled for that address to see the plot in my local machine. My question is, what do I need to do so that if I tell anyone, the ip address of my server (let's say 123.12.12.123) and the port where to look for, that they can see the plot without the problem of SSH ing ? Is it at all possible?

**Update**: Required code for details of implementation. Since it needs two files to read the data for plotting, I have included them [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1__N7igua6KAy1mQpzYkuUzU5-KWOe3FP?usp=sharing).

```
''' 
Use the ``bokeh serve`` command to run the example by executing: bokeh serve sliders.py
at your command prompt. Then navigate to the URL-http://localhost:5006/sliders
in your browser.
'''

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import Button, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

# Callbacks
def update_data():
   print("reading new data")
   df1 = read_pickle('weeklydata2.pkl')
   source.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(df1)

# Set up data
df =read_pickle('weeklydata1.pkl')
f = dict(OAT='green', SAT='orange', OAH='red')
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

# Set up plot
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime")

for i in df.columns:
   p.line('index',
          i,
          source=source,
          legend_label=i,
          line_color=f[i])
   p.circle('index',
            i,
            source=source,
            size=10,
            color=f[i])

# Set up widgets
button = Button(label='Refresh Plot')
button.on_click(update_data)
inputs = column(button)

curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, p, width=800))
curdoc().title = "Time Series of Temp., Setpoint and Humidity Variables"
```

This generates the output

> 2019-11-26 10:53:19,916 Starting Bokeh server version 1.4.0 (running on Tornado 6.0.3)
>
> 2019-11-26 10:53:19,918 User authentication hooks NOT provided (default user enabled)
>
> 2019-11-26 10:53:19,921 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/datashow
>
> 2019-11-26 10:53:19,921 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 7116
>
> 2019-11-26 10:53:23,385 WebSocket connection opened
>
> 2019-11-26 10:53:23,385 ServerConnection created
>
> reading new data
>
> reading new data
>
> 2019-11-26 10:54:41,574 WebSocket connection closed: code=1001, reason=None
>
> Interrupted, shutting down

I want to keep the server running at the above mentioned port so that anyone can only see the plot live with a choice to update it if they want to. Here the update will only work once at I have provided hardcoded a static datasource. But I guess you understand my point?

Answer (score 0):

Only with that infomration the only way to achieve what you want would be with an iptables rule that would redirect all the MAC addresses that are different from yours to the desired port. For example something like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -m mac ! --mac-source 11:22:33:44:55:66 -j DNAT --to 123.12.12.123:5006
```

Comment: Sorry for the late follow up: so would I provide anyone with the ip for my server and it would automatically redirect to the port 5006?

Comment: It would make that anyone with MAC source address diferent than yours to redirect from port 22 to port 5006 in order to avoid the use of SSH

Comment: What address/ip and port should I provide to people in that case? 123.12.12.123:22 or something else? Added an example of what I am doing

Answer (score 0):

- The app that listens to port 5006 should bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 (unless it already does and the restriction is caused by a firewall)
- Traffic to port 5006 should be allowed (by the server's own firewall and/or by nearby routers) or you can reconfigure the app to listen to some allowed port (80, 443...).

Comment: I am sorry but since I am new to this, I am not sure if I fully understand what needs to be done to allow others to see the port. Yes, I can change the port to some allowed ports like 80,443 as you mentioned. But would just doing that ensure that if I give someone the address lets say (123.12.12.123) and port 80 ie 123.12.12.123:80 they will see the plot?

Actually I was looking for a working example online that could show a simple example, but it was difficult for me to find one.

Comment: Not knowing you application and/or the server, it is hard to be specific. Your app can connect directly (Java+Springboot, Python+Django or Flask), with a middleware (Tomcat), or be behind a server (Apache or Nginx) or any of this in a Docker container. Each would call for a different solution... Not speaking of the network policies at your university...

Comment: Do you know of any working example that I can refer to online. I could not figure out the correct term to look for. I was researching some more in the mean time and figured that I will go down the Python+Flask path. Not sure about the middleware details.

Comment: You misunderstood me. Your first problem is to figure out how the current application works, and report here so that we can make adequate suggestions.

Comment: I have created a reproducible code of the implementation of what I want to display on the server port. Is there anything else that might be needed?